# opencv and multiprocessing read error [h264 @ 0x7fa02816f2c0] error while decoding MB 26 11, bytestream -7

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing

I read this thread and got the stream working using threading. [opencv read error:[h264 @ 0x8f915e0] error while decoding MB 53 20, bytestream -7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233433/opencv-read-errorh264-0x8f915e0-error-while-decoding-mb-53-20-bytestream).

As suggested in the upvoted answer I use different functions for reading the stream and processing the frames as follows.

```py
def Receive(stream, raw_frame_queue):
    print("start Receive")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Not successfull")
            break
        raw_frame_queue.put(frame)
        time.sleep(0.25)
    cap.release()

def Prepare(raw_frame_queue):
    print("Start preparing")
    frame_buffer = deque([], 30)
    while True:
        if raw_frame_queue.empty():
            continue
        frame_buffer.append(raw_frame_queue.get())
        lots of other stuff
```

everything works as expected with threading:

```py
import queue
import threading

raw_frame_queue = queue.Queue()

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=Receive, args=((RTSP_URL, raw_frame_queue)))
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=Prepare, args=((raw_frame_queue),))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Using multiprocessing however the frames can't be decoded:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
raw_frame_queue = Queue()

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=Receive, args=((RTSP_URL, raw_frame_queue)))
    p2 = Process(target=Prepare, args=((raw_frame_queue),))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

The errormessage are something like `[h264 @ 0x7fa02816f2c0] error while decoding MB 26 11, bytestream -7` for every single frame.
Quick sidenote, `"Not successfull"` is never printed, so the frames can always be grabbed

Comment: Thank you for the provided links. They all are talking about threading however, which I got to work. The problem described however is in context of multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still haven't got this to work directly, but since the Receive function is not very compute heavy. I ended up running it in a different thread and all other functions such as Prepare, which are all quite a bit more complex and CPU bounded in different processes. This keep parallelism at an sufficient level for my application.