# How to ignore "error while decoding" and continue live stream?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, rtsp

I am having the RTSP FFMPEG issue while decoding in OpenCV Livestream using PyFlask. I get this particular error `[h264 @ 0x23a0be0] error while decoding MB 59 42, bytestream -13` and then the live stream stops abruptly.

This is my code and seems like it when ret became `False` it goes to else statement and something happens there and the whole livestream gets stucked.

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture('RTSP LINK HERE')

def gen_frames():  # generate frame by frame from camera
    while (camera.isOpened()):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if ret == True:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        else:
            continue

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen_frames(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

I also tried using threading as they mentioned here [opencv read error:[h264 @ 0x8f915e0] error while decoding MB 53 20, bytestream -7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233433/opencv-read-errorh264-0x8f915e0-error-while-decoding-mb-53-20-bytestream) but I get the same error.

Comment: did you try: `try` and then `except` or `catch` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I am facing the same problem. The livestream is getting stuck abruptly

Comment: source stream corrupted. not an issue with opencv. reproduce with plain ffmpeg, without python, without opencv.

Comment: This could Happen when packages are lost you could try rtsp with TCP maybe opencv use UDP.  But this Just mean that it can decode the current Packet but it should Not Break the Loop, you will see h246 artifacts when U Display it

Comment: Hi @Christoph, Thanks let me try it.. yes, I don't want to break the loop.